# Datatables: select events and group by day in range

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

I have a table where I store events with start and end date.

```
+----+--------+------------+------------+
| id | event  |   start    |    end     |
+----+--------+------------+------------+
|  1 | event1 | 2018-02-01 | 2018-02-03 |
|  2 | event2 | 2018-02-01 | 2018-02-03 |
|  3 | event3 | 2018-02-01 | 2018-02-01 |
|  4 | event4 | 2018-02-01 | 2018-02-02 |
|  5 | event5 | 2018-02-02 | 2018-02-03 |
+----+--------+------------+------------+
```

I would like to group the events by day and show them in a datatable.

```
2018-01-01           
  1            event1  
  2            event2  
  3            event3  
  4            event4  
2018-02-02           
  1            event1  
  2            event2  
  4            event4  
  5            event5  
2018-02-03           
  1            event1  
  2            event2  
  5            event5
```

How do I correctly select the records from the table and how can I group them into a datatable?

Comment: How are you grouping the data?

Comment: I've updated my anwser (Missing `[]` in `$group[$dt][] = $record ; `)

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop around your records. For each event, compute all days, for each day, store event name in an array with this day as key. Sort the array by keys. Then, use this array to build your table.

Pseudo code :

```
$group = [] ;
foreach ($records as $record) {
    $time = strtotime($records['start']);
    $end = strtotime($records['end']);
    while ($time <= $end) {
        $dt = date('Y-m-d', $time);
        $group[$dt][] = $record; 
        $time = strtotime('+1 day', $time);
    }
}
ksort($group);
var_dump($group) ;
```

Now you can loop around `$group` to build your table :

```
foreach ($group as $date => $record) {
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT id, event FROM `testtt` WHERE start="2018-02-01"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qbdu.png)